# Not able to start postgres on fedora

Tags: postgresql, fedora-25

[mayur@mayuresh ~]$ systemctl start postgresql

```
Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

[mayur@mayuresh ~]$ systemctl status postgresql.service

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)  
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-05-21 11:43:51 IST; 46s ago  
  Process: 6984 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postgresql-check-db-dir %N (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 21 11:55:48 mayuresh.localhost systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...  
May 21 11:55:48 mayuresh.localhost systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1   
May 21 11:55:48 mayuresh.localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.  
May 21 11:55:48 mayuresh.localhost systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Unit entered failed state.   
May 21 11:55:48 mayuresh.localhost systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Not able to find any proper solution.

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL server log file. Try to start the server as OS user `postgres` with `pg_ctl start` and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe as mentioned [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) there was some problem with data initialisation. It worked!!